# XAML How to Style Checkbox's box color?

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox

I am do a UWP project that needed to style a checkbox's box color. I see I am able to change the label color of the checkbox, but not the box itself.

[image]

My coding is relatively simple:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cb1" Content="Checkbox" Foreground="#FFE01515"/>
```

I googled a numbers of website, I know custom template is the solution but I don't know how to build the resource.

So, how to style the box of the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly, you can setup `BorderBrush` property

If you want determine a own CheckBox style take the default style and change what you want

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CheckBox -->
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,5,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CombinedStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedNormal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                 To="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckedStrokeThickness}"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedDisabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedNormal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                 To="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckedStrokeThickness}"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                 To="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckedStrokeThickness}"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateNormal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="&#xE73C;" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="&#xE73C;" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="&#xE73C;" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="&#xE73C;" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1"
                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle"
                        Fill="Transparent"
                        Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                        StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}"
                        UseLayoutRounding="False"
                        Height="20"
                        Width="20" />
                                <FontIcon x:Name="CheckGlyph"
                        FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                        Glyph="&#xE001;"
                        FontSize="20"
                        Foreground="Green"
                        Opacity="0" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: WPF, making things that should be simple a pain in the ass since .NET 3.0

Comment: Thanks Andrii Krupka. One more question though. How do I get the Default Style like above? Let's say a Textblock. How you get it in VS2015?